# How to pass a record or eloquent to controller as parameter in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Imagine we have `$query = User::get();` in controller and in blade:

```
 @foreach($users as $user) <a href="{{route('user.show',['user'=>$user])}}" @endforeach
```

and route:

```
route::get('user/show/{user}','UserController@show')->name('user.show')
```

In show function:

```
public function show($user){
 dd($user);
}
```

it only show the id but I expect to show a record of database of the user

Comment: its should be like this `route('user.show', $user->id)` and your `show(User $user)` like this

Comment: @ZeroOne it is recommended to pass an associative array to the `route` helper for the parameters and laravel will pull the correct field from the model when passed like that, that is why models have a `getRouteKey` method, which is also why implicit route model binding works

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

```php
public function show(User $user){ <---- invoke user model
 dd($user);
}
```

and one more issue

```php
 @foreach($users as $user) <a href="{{route('user.show',['user'=>$user->id])}}" @endforeach
```

fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your

```
public function show($user){
       dd($user);
}
```

to

```
public function show(User $user){
       dd($user);
}
```

and

```
@foreach($users as $user) 
     <a href="{{route('user.show',['user'=>$user])}}" 
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($users as $user) 
     <a href="{{route('user.show', $user->id)}}" 
@endforeach
```